# Customize Hyper Link into a Button Shiny R

Tags: html, css, r, shiny, shinydashboard

I am trying to customize many hyperlinks into an action button in shiny. I have found some code on stack overflow that shows how to do this in CSS/HTML. However I am a bit confused on where to place this in my shiny code if i want to have it apply to all links with class == "button".

Below is html code for the button

```
.button {
  font: bold 11px Arial;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
  color: #333333;
  padding: 2px 6px 2px 6px;
  border-top: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
  border-right: 1px solid #333333;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #333333;
  border-left: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
}
```

Below is a shiny application. Where should I insert the above code so that when i call "class = Button" in the anchor tag, the hyperlink will look like a button.

```
ui <- fluidPage(

  titlePanel("Hello Shiny!"),

  
  sidebarLayout(

      textOutput('test')
    ),

    
    mainPanel(
       a("Click Here To Learn More",href="https://google.com",  class = "button")

    
    )
  )
)
```

I appreciate the help

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
CSS <- "
.button {
  font: bold 11px Arial;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
  color: #333333;
  padding: 2px 6px 2px 6px;
  border-top: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
  border-right: 1px solid #333333;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #333333;
  border-left: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
}"

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  titlePanel("Hello Shiny!"),
  tags$head(
    tags$style(HTML(CSS))
  ),
  
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(textOutput('test')),
    
    mainPanel(
      a("Click Here To Learn More",href="https://google.com",  class = "button")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$test <- renderText({paste("Test 1")})
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image: output]